# Program to display cron jobs working and when they are invoked

Tags: 16.04, cron

Why isn't there an application in which I can see an overview over all of the cron jobs, when they are invoked, user running the file and what file it's being run on. Something like below:

```
~$ showmecron
root    5 8 * * 6   /etc/cron.d/script-a
root    5 8 * * 6   /etc/cron.d/script-b
userX   weekly      /etc/cron.weekly/script-c
userY   daily       /etc/cron.daily/script-d
```

Is there a program which shows this?

Comment: Karl, you have /var/spool/cron directory and /etc/cron.d (+weekly, daily) where you can cat all the files. why you do not write own script?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Indeed one can do so, however that still won't display the time they are invoked or on which user :(

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Comment: Maybe this helps too: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-schedule

Comment: "Why isn't there..."? is answered simply enough: Because nobody needed one, so they didn't write one. Consider perhaps changing the wording to "How can I...". There are  several ways to do it.